# Jenkins configuration - svn URL to monitor specific directory in branches

Tags: svn, url, jenkins

I have reviewed the resulting "Questions that may already have your answer" as well as many variations of a google search.
2 scenarios were found that used a different solution, which does not meet our needs.
-[Build from trunk or branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751735/how-to-configure-a-single-jenkins-job-to-make-the-release-process-from-trunk-or)'
- [SVN URL variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10120475/make-jenkins-build-multiple-configurations-with-variable-svn-urls)
The end result I am trying to achieve is a single job that monitors a specific project under all branches.
For instance, a checkin to svn://svn.host/branches/*/project/code/place would trigger a build.
I have tried to wildcard the svn URL as such with regular expressions and continue to receive notification the the URL is invalid.
Has anyone been able to configure a single Jenkins job that monitors a specific directory under multiple branches?
Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a finite set of branches you wish to monitor then you define them all separately with the 'Add more locations' button in the SVN configuration.

If you have a more complex configuration then you could achieve this by having a job to reconfigure your main job using [Job DSL Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) which allows jobs to be reconfigured  with groovy

```
def branches

"svn ls svn://XXX/branches/".execute().with { br ->
  branches  = text.split()
  br.waitFor()
}

job{
  using "__xxxxx" //important or it replaces job with only svn entries
  name  "__xxxxx"
  scm{

    svn( 'svn://XXX/trunk/a/bit/deeper', 'trunk')
    {
      branches.each(){ br ->
        it / locations << 'hudson.scm.SubversionSCM_-ModuleLocation' {
          remote "svn://XXX/branches/${br}/a/bit/deeper"
          local "${br}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That would work for a finite set of branches, thanks.  However, we do continue to increment the branches, so would not work in our situation.  Still trying to find a good solution.

Comment: you can run the groovy code in a separate job and it will add (and remove) svn settings to the main job as the branches change